# Django Rest Framework: How to work with Foreign Key in Serializer?

Tags: python, django, database, django-rest-framework

I am new to Django and I have this DB Schema
[DB Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhMUF.png)

I have coded schema in models.py

```py
from django.db import models
from auth_jwt.models import User


class Board(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    board_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    board_desc = models.CharField(max_length=120)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.board_name


class Column(models.Model):
    column_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    board = models.ForeignKey(Board, null=True, related_name="board", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.column_name


class Todo(models.Model):
    todo_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    todo_desc = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    column = models.ForeignKey(Column, null=True, related_name="column", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.todo_name
```

serializers.py

```py
from rest_framework import serializers

from .models import Board, Todo, Column


class BoardSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Board
        fields = ["id", "board_name", "board_desc"]


class ColumnSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    board = BoardSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Column
        fields = ["id", "column_name", "board"]
        depth = 1


class TodoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    column = ColumnSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Todo
        fields = ["todo_name", "todo_desc", "column"]
        depth = 1
```

But whenever I POST data to Todo Model it returns

```sh
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: api_todo.column_id
```

Post Data

```json
{
    "todo_name": "satyam",
    "todo_desc": "dsa",
    "column": {
        "column_name": "Todo",
        "board": {
            "board_name": "Todo",
            "board_desc": "Whatta Day!"
        }
    }
}
```

Views.py

```
class TodoView(ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = TodoSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        return Todo.objects.filter(user=user)

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response({"todo": serializer.data}, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

        return Response({"error": serializer.errors}, status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

What is causing this error? is it serializers.py? Or should I also include id within POST data?
This is my first time implementing the multiple relations model Django app. Some tips would be appericated!!
Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: did you run makemigrations and migrate commands?

Comment: Yes @ruddra I have ran those commands

Comment: @SatyamKulkarni also use blank=True for empty model foreign key fields.
Make migrations and then try.

Comment: Did you run `makemigrations` and `migrate` after adding the `null=True`?

Comment: It might be with your migrations. IF you are not working in a production db you can rename the `db.sqlite3` to db2.sqlite3 and delete the old one. Also, delete the migration files (not the folder), migrate, makemigrations and migrate again. Then you will see the results you want. 

The issue you are facing might be by deleting some migration file or you expanded your  db and now you have a shorted one. Try this approach and tell me later.

Comment: @EliasPrado I will try it